# Why are my text not displaying on the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is my html:

```
<div id="counter" class="group">
<span id="days"> <em>Days</em></span> 
<span id="hours"> <em>Hours</em></span>
<span id="mins"> <em>Minutes</em></span>
<span id="seconds"> <em>Seconds</em></span> 
</div>
```

The Text "Days", "Hours", "Minutes" and "Seconds" does not appear on my browser. Kindly help

Comment: Could you elaborate what your question is asking? What is exactly meant by 'JavaScript countdown' here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly are you querying about, but if you are asking how to  make elements by javascript is:

```
const days = document.createElement('span');
days.innerText = 'Days';
document.body.appendChild(days);
```